# In Game of Thrones, is it possible to moving back units after winning a combat following March Order?

Tags: game-of-thrones

May I move back some of the units after winning a combat? I mean, if there is time for defeated troops to retreat there will definitely be time for winning troops to move back as well. Does that not make sense?

I couldn't find any mention in the rulebook specifying that the winning units all have to stay in the conquered territory, that some (or even all) cannot move back after winning. I don't see why you can move back if you lose but you can't move back if you win? It should be even easier for winners to move back as they should be in better shape.

Answer (score 1):

The attacker does not have the opportunity to retreat if the attacker wins the combat.  The only allowance for retreating is for the losing army:

> After suffering casualties, the losing army must retreat from the embattled area (supporting units do not retreat.)

There is no mention of what happens to the winning units after combat because nothing needs to happen to them.  Combat began by them moving to the territory they are trying to conquer.  Thus, all that needs to happen in cleanup following an attacker victory is the removal of order tokens:

> After combat is completed, remove the attacking player’s March
>   Order token from the game board.
>
> If the combat was won by the attacker, remove any Order token the
>   defender had assigned to the embattled area (if one remains) as well
>   as any Power token in the area (which would exist if the defending
>   player had previously established control there, see page 24)

One pseudo-exception to this is Loras Tyrell, who moves the march order with the attacking units if they are victorious.  You can use Loras to move attacking units back to their original territory after they win a battle, but doing so is not a retreat (these units will remain upright) and is not immediate (this cannot be done before your next turn in order resolution).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **No**.  While it does makes sense to be able, it is not part of the rules.

[image]

see [rules of Agot](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/30/4f/304f72e3-4fe4-4f91-bfbe-75133161b092/va65_agot2_rulebook_web.pdf)

One major effect for this rule: it will make siege towers super strong (not saying if it is good or bad).

Comment: The siege towers wouldn't be able to, since they cannot retreat following defeat either. Why is there no mention to what happens to the winning units after combat? I wish there was. It just discusses the losers. Anyway, I'll do as you say, thanks!

Comment: no mention to what happens to the winning units after combat? because nathing happens to them.  It would be too long to write all the things that do *not* accur...